# NetBeans report error in src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image.png" in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, el

Everywhere where I have:

```
<img alt="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image.png" >
```

NetBeans report an error:

```
Bad value "   /images/image.png" for attribute "src" on element "img": WHITESPACE in PATH.
Syntax of IRI reference:
Any URL. For example: '/hello', '#canvas', or 'http://example.org/'. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as '%20'.

From line 42, column 21; to line 42, column 64
(Rule Category: Attributes)
```

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Don't use Java code in JSP file. Use JSTL. `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}`

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use Java code in JSP file. Use JSTL.** You can get context path using below code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}
// OR
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

**Read more on this :** [Comparing JSTL and JSP Scriptlet Programming](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30334)